# How to use add_error on a nested changeset?

Tags: elixir, ecto

From what I understand in the [documentation for add_error](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#add_error/4), It can only apply to the top-level changeset.

How do I use add_error on a nested changeset though?

For example, take these schemas:

```
defmodule MyApp.Person do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "people" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :other_field_made_to_fail, :string

    has_many :addresses, MyApp.Address
  end

  def changeset(person, attrs) do
    person
    |> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name, :other_field_made_to_fail])
    |> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Address do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "addresses" do
    field :street_name, :string
    field :city, :string
    field :state, :string

    belongs_to :person, MyApp.Person
  end

  def changeset(address, attrs) do
    address
    |> cast(attrs, [:street_name, :city, :state])
    |> validate_required([:city, :state])
    |> cast_assoc(:person, with: &MyApp.Person.changeset/2, required: true)
  end
end
```

And take this data input:

```
%{
  "address" => %{
    "city" => "Test City",
    "state" => "Test State",
    "person" => %{
      "first_name" => "John",
      "last_name" => "Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

And this resulting changeset:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<
  changes: %{
    address: #Ecto.Changeset<
      changes: %{
        city: "Test City",
        state: "Test State"
        person: #Ecto.Changeset<
          changes: %{
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Doe"
          }
        >
      },
      errors: []
      valid?: true
    >
  }
>
```

How would I use `add_error/4` to add an error to `:other_field_made_to_fail` inside the nested `:person` attribute and keep the rest of the changeset intact?

Comment: Why would you want to handle this from the outermost schema in the first place? The error is to be added in `MyApp.Person.changeset/2` during validation of `Person` so that it would be propagated through `cast_assoc/2` and may be handled with [`Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#traverse_errors/2) afterward.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Because the `:other_field_made_to_fail` isn't part of the user input. I wanted to raise an error to this field based on the rest of the user's input. This means that I need to intervene with the changeset instead of letting Ecto run its course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. In case there are other people who are interested, the solution is to call [update_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#update_change/3) on your changeset and call a function as the 3rd argument which represents your nested changeset:

```
Ecto.Changeset.update_change(changeset, :person, fn person_changeset ->
  Ecto.Changeset.add_error(person_changeset, :other_field_made_to_fail, "error message here")
end)
```

The end result is an updated `Address` changeset that now includes the `Person` changeset with an error on it.

You can also use `update_change/3` to do other changeset functions into your nested changesets and it will return the updated nested changeset.